# Pin an array in memory and construct a Bitmap using that buffer

Tags: c#, .net, image, memory-management

I'm using some resources in the code below to pin an array in memory and construct a `Bitmap` using that buffer. I'm not sure if I'm handling all of the resourced in the proper way.

I'm interested if the way I'm handling the `GCHandle` and other resources in the constructor in a safe manner, so there are no resource leaks.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Model
{
    public class FastImage
    {
        private const int BytesPerPixel = 4;
        private readonly byte[] _buffer;
        private const int ExtraSpace = 0;

        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }

        public FastImage(int width, int height)
        {
            Width = width;
            Height = height;
            _buffer = new byte[Width * Height * BytesPerPixel];
        }

        public FastImage(Bitmap from)
        {
            Width = from.Width;
            Height = from.Height;
            _buffer = new byte[Width * Height * BytesPerPixel];
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(_buffer);
            try
            {
                var address = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(_buffer, 0);
                var stride = BytesPerPixel * Width;
                var pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
                using (var fastBitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height, stride, pixelFormat, address))
                {
                    using (var fastBitmapGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(fastBitmap))
                        fastBitmapGraphics.DrawImageUnscaled(from, 0, 0);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                handle.Free();
            }
        }

        public Color GetPixel(int x, int y)
        {
            var i = y * BytesPerPixel + x;
            return Color.FromArgb(_buffer[i], _buffer[i + 1], _buffer[i + 2], _buffer[i + 3]);
        }

        public void SetPixel(int x, int y, Color color)
        {
            var i = y * BytesPerPixel + x;
            _buffer[i] = color.A;
            _buffer[i + 1] = color.R;
            _buffer[i + 2] = color.G;
            _buffer[i + 3] = color.B;
        }

        public void Save(string filename)
        {
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(_buffer);
            try
            {
                var address = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(_buffer, 0);
                var stride = BytesPerPixel * Width;
                var pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
                using (var fastBitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height, stride, pixelFormat, address))
                {
                    fastBitmap.Save(filename);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                handle.Free();
            }
        }

        public void Save(MemoryStream stream, ImageFormat format)
        {
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(_buffer);
            try
            {
                var address = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(_buffer, 0);
                var stride = BytesPerPixel * Width;
                var pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
                using (var fastBitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height, stride, pixelFormat, address))
                {
                    fastBitmap.Save(stream, format);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                handle.Free();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement` is considered obsolete, you could use the `AddrOfPinnedObject` methdod of `GCHandle` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot complain about your code much. You declare variables as `readonly` where appropriate and you use the `try/finally` block to free the resources.

The only things I don't like are these properties

> ```
> public int Width { get; set; }
> public int Height { get; set; }
> ```

you don't want them to be settable. The setter should be `private`.

---

and the magic numbers here (and in other places).

> ```
> _buffer[i + 1] = color.R;
> _buffer[i + 2] = color.G;
> _buffer[i + 3] = color.B;
> ```

I find you should use a helper class for them:

```
static class ColorOffset
{
    public const int Alpha = 0;
    public const int Red = 1;
    public const int Green = 2;
    public const int Blue = 3;
}

_buffer[i + ColorOffset.Red] = color.R;
_buffer[i + ColorOffset.Green] = color.G;
_buffer[i + ColorOffset.Blue] = color.B;
```